# Integrating SMS service in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sms

Does anyone know how to implement SMS Plugin in Jenkins?!
I have searched in Jenkins and found the plugin (SMS Notification), however it involves cost.
I want to integrate SMS without bearing the cost.  Any help is appreciated!! :)

Thanks

Comment: SMS are usually not for free. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

This is a legitimate question!

1. Make sure you are using Jenkins 2.x
2. Download the email-ext plugin from https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext
3. Install the plugin and restart Jenkins
4. Configure your job -- in the Post Build Actions, select Editable Email Notification and enter the emails for the cellular company being used in the Project Recipient List

   T-mobile would be phonenumber@tmomail.net

   Verizon would be phonenumber@vtext.com

   AT&T would be phonenumber@txt.att.net ... etc
5. Make sure you avoid the problem I had: Your System Admin e-mail address must have a valid email address.

Comment: It'd be unwieldy to support every less-common carrier, but I guess you get what you pay for...

Comment: As long as the carrier supplies an email address, this works without any cost to the company sending the text. It's not about the system supporting a carrier. It's just simply sending an email just like any other email. In the USA, the carriers provide the email and the end user has a text plan. Many text plans send and receive unlimited data/text these days. Our set up is working insanely well now. Free and timely. Better than an installed monitoring system.
You need to know your user's carrier texting email and be sending the email from a real and valid email address.