# Jenkins does not send emails to cell phone emails xxxxxxxxxx@tmomail.net and @vnet.com

Tags: email, jenkins, sms

We are using Jenkins 2.16, Email Extension Plugin 2.47, and Status Monitor Plugin in order to check our site to make sure it is up. The goal is to send an email to our cell phones to alert us that the check failed.

Everything works, but no one is getting texts!

Emails sent to name@ourcompany.com work. Emails sent to @gmail.com work! Emails going to 1234567899@tmomail.net do not work. I have a powershell on that server that sends an email to 1234567899@tmomail.net and I do get a text.

I tried the sms Jenkins plugin but it requires a paid membership and my company does not approve.

I will next try a hack where Jenkins calls the PS1 to run using the Powershell plugin ... but this is totally dumb and harder to manage. Impossible to manage on the Jenkins front end.

What gives?!? Any Ideas on how to make JUST Jenkins work ??
I see no errors on the console output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AT9M.png

This question is similar to 
[Integrating SMS service in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47221035/integrating-sms-service-in-jenkins)
... but no one has answered.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I had an email address for the Jenkins administrative address in my global settings that was bogus (no@reply.com). I changed it to a legit company email and texts are now being sent.

I got this solution by posting a bug on the Jenkins forum and they gave me some possible solutions there.